# Styled tables in trac's wiki

Tags: wiki, trac, table-styles

I have a table in trac's wiki, just a regular html table, and manager asks me to add some styling. What is the best way to accomplish this? I can write a script which inserts style attribute to every DOM element needed, but of course I wish to use something like `style` tag or anything else making this task less kludgy.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what Trac version you use. In general you can access Trac default CSS styling like so (wiki markup):

```
{{{
#!html
<table class="wiki">
  <tr>
    <th>Great stuff</th>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>some more...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
}}}
```

You find all valid CSS styles by [browsing the repository](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-0.12.3/trac/htdocs/css/trac.css#L387) (link is valid for current stable 0.12.3, but finding the same for other versions should be trivial from there).